# Javascript / Jquery Table Plugin with Multiple Operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am looking for Javascript / Jquery Table Plugin, which should have following functionalities included in it.

- Fixed Header of table (Header Lock with Elements Scrollable)
- Few Columns Locked while scrolling (say first two columns)
- Drag and drop with column
- Column Resizing (like Excel)
- Column Priority Change in Responsive views (e.g Table Saw Like Plugin)
- Horizontal Scroll on column exceeding on than current views
- Sorting

I have group of plugin's which gave me these individual options separately. I am looking combination of it.

If anyone have any good reference link, then please suggest.

Regards,
Sopo

Comment: Jquery dataTables may be a good choice. I use it to get these functionalities and many other with this plugin.

Comment: Hi Lelio, thanks for the comment. i have tried your suggestion. Out of my 7 requirements only 4 are there (Sorting, Drag and drop, Responsive views without priority for columns, Header fixed with vertical scrolling ). of these drag and drop is not working proper and responsive views is also not controllable.

Comment: this is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s8n4mf6d/

Comment: I am not involved in the plugin development. Feel free to use the good guideline on their site and to enhance their functionalities if needed. Afaik also sorting is working out of the box btw!!!

Comment: I have found column fixed option also in it, but its not working proper as it gives dragging option to fixed columns. Working on these issues